# Che cosa significa "voler dire piú della metà"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Una mattina arrivò al Boscaccio un uomo di Rocchetta e raccontò ai figli che lui doveva aver visto loro padre, però era già una settimana fa: – L’ho visto sul mercato del mio paese, – disse: – io ero lí a sentir uno che contava d’un suo conoscente che s’era impiccato nella settimana. Appena finito, entra nel nostro cerchio un uomo che era vostro padre di sicuro, mette una mano sulla spalla a quello che aveva contato e gli fa: «Ha avuto del coraggio, quel vostro amico, ha avuto del coraggio», e poi se n’è andato non so verso dove. 
>         Tutti restarono lí e solo dopo un po’ il figlio piú vecchio domandò cosa quel fatto voleva dire. – **Mi sembra che voglia dire piú della metà**, – rispose quello di Rocchetta. Basta, dovettero mettersi tutti in mezzo perché il figlio piú vecchio non lo strangolasse, in paga d’essersi fatto tre colline per metterli sulla strada di loro padre e invece di passargli da bere.

Il brano fa riferimento a un contadino che era sparito. La mia domanda è sul significato della frase "Mi sembra che voglia dire piú della metà" che appare in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "metà" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho saputo trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sebbene non possa trovare riferimenti bibliografici relativi a questo modo di dire (anzi, trovo l'unico utilizzo ne *La malora*), l'espressione sembra un calco di *"dire le cose a metà"*, che la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meta/) definisce come

> non esprimersi chiaramente, dire e non dire.

Il significato dunque è **"suggerire abbastanza da comprendere il vero significato delle sue parole"**.

In questo caso, il fatto che il padre abbia chiamato coraggioso l'uomo impiccato sottintende per l'uomo di Rocchetta che il padre volesse suicidarsi, e spiegherebbe con la sua morte la sua sparizione.

Comment: Questa risposta, però, non mi sembra tanto diversa di quella di @Gio. Per questa ragione, mi sono permessa la libertà di "discancellarla" (non so se si possa dire così).

Comment: @Charo Non so che bug avesse il mio browser, ma quando ho aperto questa domanda, mi diceva che non c'erano risposte! Quella di Gio era quindi stata cancellata?

Comment: Sì, era stata cancellata e soltanto gli utenti con molta reputazione potevano vederla. Tuttavia, mi piace il modo in cui hai spiegato il significato.

Comment: @Charo felice di essere stata utile! Se ci fosse stata quando ho visto la domanda, avrei semplicemente suggerito il significato come aggiunta, con un commento. :)

Comment: Questo accade spesso qui: quando gli utenti vedono che c'è già una risposta non ne aggiungono un'altra. Ed è invece arricchente per il sito avere parecchie risposte a una stessa domanda.

Comment: Sono d’accordo che questa risposa sia più chiara. Suggerisco di aggiungere il link di Treccani relativo a *fare le cose a metà* http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meta/ -   meglio una risposta completa  che una divisa in due.

Comment: Grazie @Gio, aggiunta!

Comment: Scusa, @Gio, ma non sono d'accordo con il fatto che la tua risposta debba essere cancellata. Penso che lo spirito di SE, perlomeno quello che io intendo da [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language), è che è positivo per il sito avere parecchie risposte a una stessa domanda.

Comment: @Charo - capisco quello che vuoi dire, ma   vale nel caso in cui diverse risposte diano diverse interpretazioni. In questo caso la risposta era la stessa, e  vista la buona spiegazione data da LinuxBlanket, mi sembra corretto salvare la sua.

Comment: @Gio: Non sono d'accordo: cercando nei siti web di SE dedicati a lingue si possono trovare esempi di domande che chiedono sul significato di un vocabolo o un'espressione le diverse risposte delle quali non sono interpretazioni diverse. Io avrei preferito lasciare la tua risposta (quella originale, non quello che c'è adesso), ma se tu la vuoi cancellare non possiamo fare niente.